# Techniques to Reduce CPU to GPU Data Transfer Latency

Tags: optimization, memory, cuda, data-transfer, latency

I've been looking into ways to reduce the latency caused by transferring data back and forth from the CPU and GPU. When I first started using CUDA I did notice that data transfer between the CPU and GPU did take a few seconds, but I didn't really care because this isn't really a concern for the small programs I'm been writing. In fact, the latency probably isn't much of a problem for vast majority of the programs that utilize GPUs, video games included, because they're still a lot faster than if they would have run on the CPU.

However, I'm a bit of an HPC enthusiast and I became concerned with the direction of my studies when I saw the massive discrepancy between the Tianhe-I theoretical peak FLOPS and the actual LINPACK measured performance. This has raised my concerns about whether I'm taking the right career path.

Use of pinned memory (page-locked) memory through the use of the cudaHostAlloc() function is one method of reducing latency (quite effective), but are there any other techniques I'm not aware of? And to be clear, I'm talking about optimizing the code, not the hardware itself (that's NVIDIA and AMD's jobs).

Just as a side question, I'm aware that Dell and HP sell Tesla servers. I'm curious as to how well a GPU leverages a database application, where you would need a constant read from the hard drive (HDD or SSD), an operation only the CPU can perform,

Comment: You might find this amusing: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~skadron/Papers/bakkum_sqlite_gpgpu10.pdf

Comment: @Misha You're right, this article describes the particular the challenge I had in mind. Thanks...

Comment: Regarding the low flop-efficiency of Tianhe-IA: although GPUs have massive arithmetic power (which ideed is often difficult to fully utilize), don't forget that the GPU memory architecture also plays and important role and even compute-bound kernels can seriously outperform CPU implementations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a few ways to address CPU-GPU communication overhead - I hope that's what you mean by latency and not the latency of the transfer itself. Note that I deliberately used the term *address* instead of *reduce* as you do not necessarily need to reduce the latency if you can hide it. Also note that I am much more familiar with CUDA, so below I only refer to CUDA, but some features are also available in OpenCL.

As you mentioned **page-locked memory** has the very purpose of increasing. Additionally, one can map page-locked host memory to the GPU, mechanism which enables direct access of the data allocated from the GPU kernel without the need for additional data-transfer. This mechanism is called **zero-copy** transfer and it is useful if data is read/written only once accompanied by a substantial amount of computation and for GPUs with no separate memory (mobile). However, if the kernel accessing the zero-copied data is not strongly compute-bound and therefore the latency of data access cannot be hidden, page-locked but not mapped memory will be more efficient. Additionally, if the data does not fit into the GPU memory, zero-copy will still work.
Note that excessive amount of page-locked memory can cause serious slowdown on the CPU side.

Approaching the problem from a different angle, as tkerwin mentioned, **asynchronous transfer** (wrt the CPU thread talking to the GPU) is the key to hide CPU-GPU transfer latency by overlapping computation on the CPU with the transfer. This can be achieved with `cudaMemcpyAsync()` as well as using zero-copy with asynchronous kernel execution.
One can take this even further by using multiple streams to overlap transfer with kernel execution. Note that stream scheduling might need special attention for good overlapping; Tesla and Quadro cards have dual-DMA engine which enables simultaneous data transfer to and from GPU. 
Additionally, with CUDA 4.0 it became easier to use a GPU from multiple CPU threads, so in a multi-threaded CPU code each thread can send its own data to the GPU and launch kernels easier.

Finally, **[GMAC](http://code.google.com/p/adsm)** implements an asymmetric shared memory model for CUDA. One of its very interesting features is the coherency models it provides, in particular lazy- and rolling update enabling the transfer of only data modified on the CPU in a blocked fashion.
For more details see the following paper: [Gelado et al. - An Asymmetric Distributed Shared Memory
Model for Heterogeneous Parallel Systems](http://code.google.com/p/adsm/downloads/detail?name=adsm-asplos10.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cudaMemcpyAsync()` to overlap work you're doing on the CPU with memory transfer.  This won't lower the latency of a data transfer, but it could improve the overall performance of an algorithm.  There is some information about it in the [CUDA C Best Practices](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf) guide.

Answer (score 1):

If latency is an issue, it might be worth looking into the trade offs you can make with the AMD fusion architecture. The latency you get is drastically minimised and can in some cases be faster than the CPU transfers from RAM. However, you do take a performance hit with the use of the slimmed down non-discrete GPU.